# request.headers vs. request.environ

Tags: python, cgi, bottle

I'm working with Bottle.py and Python and I'm a little confused as to the difference between the `request.headers` VS `request.environ` variables.  I'm using sessions and my session data appears in the `request.environ` variables when I enumerate the data, which leads me to the conclusion that some of this data isn't public.

How do I know which variables are public and which aren't?  What's the difference between these two variables?

Comment: One thing to observe here, is that `request.environ` variable has a set of values that are required, according with CGI specification. Also, this concepts of variables is applied to other web frameworks like Flask and Django (i guess).

Answer (score 6):

For WSGI, [environ variables](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables) are the set of CGI and other server-side environment variables that are visible to your WSGI service.

As I understand it, in Bottle `request.environ` holds *all* of the WSGI environment values, while `request.headers` is a restricted read-only view of only the values used in the header. You can access the same information through `.environ`, but `.headers` returns a specialised dictionary that ignores key case.

None of this information should be "public" outside of the server in any way.